# Cannot Compile StorageFactory.sol because "not found contracts/SimpleStorage.sol

Tags: solidity

I am doing the Solidity, Blockchain, and Smart Contract Course – Beginner to Expert Python Tutorial from freeCodeCamp and Patrick AlphaC

https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/storage_factory

Below is my code [image from my IDE too here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceAZh.png)

```
// SPDX-License_Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./SimpleStorage.sol"; 

contract StorageFactory {

    SimpleStorage[] public simpleStorageArray;

    function createSimpleStorageContact() public {
        SimpleStorage simpleStorage = new SimpleStorage();
        simpleStorageArray.push(simpleStorage);
    }
}
```

and I am getting the error:

> not found contracts/SimpleStorage.sol

even though all the files are spelt correctly and in the same folder.

Please help as I am trying to follow along with the tutorial and don't want to get left behind.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

In your picture your filename is wrong. You write `SimpleSorage` but it must be `SimpleStorage`. (Note the missing `t` in `Storage`.)